# Why my router's WAN address is different from the Public IP which will be shown in whatismyip.com

Tags: web, networking, ip, router, dhcp

I was checking my router settings  (In router configuration page, 192.168.1.1). One thing that has struck me was the WAN ip address of the router. It was 192.168.0.2, it looks like a local IP where 192 class IP's are used. I double verified it and I've attached a screenshot of the same.

[image]

Moreover, when I check my public in websites like whatismyip.com it's shown as entirely different. 
Why this happens???

[image]

Comment: You should ask this question on [su], but search there first for `cgn` as the question has been asked and answered multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

the WAN address in your case displays a local address, not the global one. So it's more likely your LAN address, which means you have some router inbetween before going on internet ?

Comment: Router is directly connected to the modem, will that leads to assign router a local IP?

Comment: It is more likely that your modem already has a built-in DHCP ? as you have two IP plages, 192.168.0.* and 192.168.1.* - So I think yes

Comment: Can you please elaborate what really happens here, I was studying my networking chapter and just gone through router settings. This has struck my curiosity.

Comment: You may want to try access http://192.168.0.1 (which will give you access to the current router) - but also http://192.168.1.1 which seems to be the DHCP server, as per what you wrote - I think your current router is actually providing a DHCP server, yet he is connected to a modem that itself provides a DHCP server with its own ip range. So your mapping would be <public ip> => <router with .1.1> => <router with .0.1> => <computer>

Comment: Thank you. I got it. 192.168.0.1 itself is another router, it shows a router page.